# Sending Video using HTTP Post Multipart entity

Tags: android, http-post

**What I want** I want to send a video from my SDcard to a server. I also want to send some parameters/value with it.

**I have tried** I have tried the following code:

```
public String SendToServer(String aUrl,File aFile)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(aUrl);

        try 
        {
            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(aFile));
            entity.addPart("video[title]", new StringBody("testVideo"));
            entity.addPart("video[type]", new StringBody("1"));
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);

            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            // Bind custom cookie store to the local context
            localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, Globals.sessionCookie);

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();  
            String Response = "";
            if (response != null) 
            {    
                Response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity); 
            }
            return Response;
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "Exception";
    }
```

**What is the problem** When I run this code, I get stuck at this line

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
```

I get no exception, no response nothing at all. Can anyone please guide me, what is the problem in here?

Comment: Have you set the internet permission or see multi-party jar file have some dependency so you are importing them or not .....?

Comment: @Khawar Did you check your Server logs?

Comment: @Vipin Yes I have set the permission and can you please explain about this dependency a bit more? May be that's the problem. I am not aware of it.

Comment: @Gaurav I don't have this server. The server returns me an XML with errors if there are any, but there is no response and exception.

Comment: @Khawar i hope your are using this apache-mime4j, httpclient, httpcore and httpmime classes which in turn requires other classes , if still the problem presist i will send the code and that I used to upload images to server .......

Comment: @Vipin I am little confused with these classes, you have mentioned. Where they are getting used in the code? I have downloaded "org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient_4.2-beta1.jar" and included it in my project.

Comment: same problem i had faced you are facing today but i dint figure out the reason i just downloaded some other version of jar and it worked

Comment: @Vipin can you please guide me which one did you use?

Comment: hey sure i will upload my project on dropbox by tonight then refer to the link alright

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above code in my question was perfect, but I had the network problem. My device was connected to a hotspot(Connectify Software). When I connected to the original network, this code worked perfect.

I recommend you people to never trust a hotspot for this kind of functionality.

Comment: how did you realized that you were on a hotspot?

Answer (score 1):

try using this way if want to send as content or esle I will upload the project by tonight

```
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(filePath), -1);
        reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
        reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed
        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Comment: But I also want to send parameters with it, otherwise i'll get error from server. How can I send "BasicNameValuePair("video[title]","testvideo")" with this code?

Comment: you can add basicnamevaluepair easliy now go with this libraries http://dl.dropbox.com/u/58874635/lib.zip

Comment: Thanks for the libraries. I have already included all of them. Can you send me a code where I can send file along with string parameters?

Comment: Here is another code that I tried, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257426/sending-video-file-with-parameters-in-httppost-android

Comment: replace the libraries with mine and it seem you want to send patameter that you can send with httppost ...like your url + "/AdServer/getvideooverlaylog?imei=" + WatchDogService.IMEI + "&data=" + data  .i,e